# Avast Antivirus thinks everything I've written in Delphi is a virus - can I ask about this on SO?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, site-recommendation

I'm encountering a problem with every executable I've written in Delphi. On my personal computer, I create just a raw simple application with literally nothing in it, just an empty form, without writing even a single line of code. I compile this EXE, run it, and Avast kills it and says it's suspicious. I also have a few Windows services which run on startup, and every one of those has been moved to the virus chest. In fact, everything in the vault is something I've written.

Anyway, since this is specific to things I've written in Delphi, is this something which I can ask on Stack Overflow?

Comment: Get a new antivirus :-p!

Comment: related other question about Delphi and antivirus : [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3733963/delphi-programs-blocked-by-kaspersky-antivirus-need-workarround)

Comment: There were Delphi viruses which manipulated the compiler to include themselves if I remember correctly, so maybe your AntiVirus Software is correct?

Comment: No, this question is not appropriate for Stack Overflow as it fails the FAQ test.

Though, this *might* be on topic for Super User if you include more information (including version numbers, dates of last updates etc.).

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau That related question is only when writing to a disk - in my case my app does literally nothing.

Comment: @TimeTravelingBobby I think it would actually be good under "practical, answerable problems that are unique to software development".

Comment: @TimeTravelingBobby Can you clarify which part of the FAQ test it fails?

Comment: Made a quick google search for "delphi written application antivirus problem" and found easily 2 SO questions, old ones. That was the first, this is [the second](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/993671/accidentally-created-a-virus). They might be more.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau That second one is quite interesting...

Comment: RANU, don't install anything you don't absolutely trust, and ditch that antiv.

Comment: @Won't I'm not installing anything, I'm writing empty applications.

Comment: You dodged my point.

Comment: @Won't I never suggested in anyways that the related questions were good, just that they were related. If you look at the second one, the answers are quite different and 81 upvotes. It's all in the way it is asked.